Is the group of homologically trivial cycles in a variety over a finite field torsion?
Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{F}_q$. Is any cycle in the Chow group $CH^i(X)$ which is trivial in $\ell$-adic cohomology automatically torsion? For abelian varieties I believe this is true by some standard results on the Beauville decomposition (see e. g. Moonen’s 2024 Arizona Winter School notes) (EDIT: this is not known in general for abelian varieties).

This is (almost) the conjecture of Beilinson (equivalent to a conjecture of Murre) that $\operatorname{CH}^i(X) \otimes \mathbf Q \to \operatorname{CH}^i(X)/\sim_{\text{num}} \otimes \mathbf Q$ is an isomorphism.

@R.vanDobbendeBruyn thanks, that’s very helpful. I wonder in what cases this is known unconditionally (I can see that the case of the product of a curve and an abelian variety, which was my original motivation, follows from the result for abelian varieties, for instance).

I don't really know about the status! Let me remark that it is (nearly) trivial for $i \in {0,1}$. I don't know at the moment if the case $i = \dim X$ is also easy, but probably it just isn't. Other than that, you'd have to dive into special families of varieties, but maybe someone more familiar with this literature should comment on that.

I don't think this is known for abelian varieties — except in the trivial cases mentioned above, and the less trivial case $\ i=\dim X -1$.

@abx you’re right, I misquoted the result, sorry.

If I remember correctly, the case $i = \mathrm{dim}(X)$ (for general $X$) is a result of Kato and Saito.
